# Eating too many nuts for weight gain

Tags: weight-gain, health-risk

I plan on eating at least 100-200g of mixed nuts (peanuts, cashews, almonds, etc.) everyday (on top of regular diet) for the purpose of gaining weight. I was wondering, can eating too much nuts cause bad health side effects?

Comment: What is the reason you want to gain weight, and are you sure that nuts are the best food to achieve that? Nuts are mostly incredibly healthy and quite frankly I'd get terribly sick of nuts if I was trying to eat enough of them to gain weight...

Comment: @NathanWheeler Not sure how to answer your question about my reason to want to gain weight, hmmm, because I want to gain?

Nuts are packed with calories.

Comment: a peanut is not a nut but a legume and also not as healthy as it's full of oil

Comment: @IMB - are you wanting to gain weight to bulk up muscle-wise, are you significantly "underweight" (based on age, height, or gender), or are you just wanting to be bigger? There's some differences in the types of foods you should eat depending on the answer to that question.

Comment: @NathanWheeler underweight.

Comment: @GraemeHutchison And nuts aren't filled with fat?!

Comment: Nuts have a lot of fat--that would be the primary negative side effect. They're healthy, in moderation, like most anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a quick read through of the search "eating nuts health risk" at Google Scholar at limited the search to 2012 and later, see http://scholar.google.se/scholar?as_ylo=2012&q=eating+nuts+health+risk&hl=sv&as_sdt=0,5. It does not seem to be any health risks.

A search for "eating nuts gaining weight" on the same source, see http://scholar.google.se/scholar?q=eating+nuts+gaining+weight&btnG=&hl=sv&as_sdt=0&as_ylo=2012 and a quick reading of the abstracts shows some result that seem to contradict that nuts are especially effective for weight gain.

10-12 years ago when I was overweight (BMI>26), the main cause was a high consumption of protein shakes and too little exercise. My idea behind the shakes was to reduce stress and I read in a book about stress that high intake of proteins would reduce stress hormones.